# R program has stopped working possibly because of Rdata file or R package

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I built a webscraper that's working fine until it  randomly stopped working. I thought it was because of my Rdata files  but I deleted the ones that I found. I now get  an error in my first function because I can't access the URL correctly anymore.

```
#Getting the number of Page
getPageNumber <- function(URL) {
  parsedDocument <- read_html(URL)
  results_per_page <- length(parsedDocument %>% html_nodes(".sr-list"))
  total_results <- parsedDocument %>%
    toString() %>%
    str_match(., 'num_results":"(.*?)"') %>% 
    .[,2] %>%
    as.integer()
  browser()
  pageNumber <- tryCatch(ceiling(total_results / results_per_page), error = function(e) {1})
  return(pageNumber)
}
getPageNumber("https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/search-results?rg_IssuePublicationDate=01%2F01%2F2010%20TO%2012%2F31%2F2010&fl_SiteID=5275&page=")
```

output should be `getPageNumber("academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/…) [1] 9`

instead I  get `NA`

Comment: This works fine for me and returns the output as `[1] 9` after removing the `browser()` line from the function.

Comment: Yeah it should work fine, for some reason the program has stopped running properly on my local machine

Comment: Restart R and try again.

Comment: I’ve tried that as well with no luck

Comment: You get "an error". Interesting. It would be more interesting to have the error message verbatim. If you just get `NA` that's not an error but an unexpected result. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes i get an unexpected result, NA